# Google Maps API; how to add a scale measure on a map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I suspect part of my problem is that I'm having a mental freeze on what the technical name for this is: But you see on http://maps.google.co.uk/ the bottom left has a small ruler indicating how big x Miles is at the current zoom level?

If I'm using google Maps API version 2, how do I add such a wonderful do-hickery widget thing to my website maps?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Google Maps API Docs - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From the [API docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/controls.html):

```
GScaleControl - a map scale
```

Comment: Knew it'd be called something obvious :-)

Answer (score 47):

Actually this is how you really get the scale to show:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  scaleControl: true,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

Answer (score -3):

I found that if you call the map as a function rather than as var and apply the scaleControl as suggested, the entire map fails to show. Still working on a solution that solves this part of the problem.

```
function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 15.5, lng: 121}, 
zoom: 10
});
```